# .NET Core 3.0 JSON serializer ignore null field

Tags: json, serialization, .net-core

Is it possible to ignore certain NULL fields when serializing with new .NET Core 3.0 JSON serializer?

```
class MyData
{
   int? a; // always serialized
   int? b; // serialized only when not NULL
}
```

(With Newtonsoft I had the option to write field-bound functions which would include custom logic to decide wheather to serialize a particular field.)

Comment: Not yet, [there's an issue about this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/40600) with a 5.0 flag. You can't even create a custom converter for this, as the `Write` method is called only for non-null values

Comment: I upvoted that request, maybe that'll help.